# Add a path to libraries for python in VS Code Windows

Tags: python, pandas, windows, visual-studio-code, cmd

I have `pandas` installed in computer via Anaconda that I downloaded previously and now when I wish to use VS Code, I tried installing `pandas` using `pip install pandas` and it said that the Requirement is already satisfied. I am not sure what path to change and how to change, though I have been able to locate pandas through `pip freeze`. Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to install pandas again even tho you're using a different IDE, you might have added the python PATH in your environment variables and that's it.
Can you just try

```
import pandas as pd
```

in your VSCode to cross check?

Comment: No it's showing error

Answer (score 0):

By default it does not recognize your anaconda environment, You need to change your python interpreter path in VS Code: check this [Change Python Interpreter](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment)

Comment: It is recognizing. Python is working fine, only libraries from conda environment are not loafing well